# Does NX make ng serve faster

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am new to [NX](https://nx.dev/)...

NX is supposed to wrap the Angular CLI and make it faster with computation caching.

This works nicely with `nx build`... Builds are done almost instantly once they have been cached.

But I wonder if also `nx serve` uses computation caching. I do not find much info about it.

In my own "performance tests" the serve command did not become faster with NX.

Why would NX not use computation caching for the serve command?

Comment: I am searching for this answer too. I do know you can add this command to nx.json. However, I don't think nx makes it faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the creator, Victor. It is not possible

By default, serve doesn't create files on disk, so nothing to be cached. This is just how webpack works. But if you, use the file-server executor (https://nx.dev/latest/node/web/file-server) serve gets cached defacto.— Victor Savkin (@victorsavkin) [February 3, 2021](https://twitter.com/victorsavkin/status/1356968136784965635?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

You can use file-server executor to improve this.

Answer (score 0):

For people still looking for ways to improve their Angular app's serve time via NX, NX released module federation which slices your host app vertically. Slicing the app improves serve time since you divide the app and serve it individually.

See the below video on what it is and how to implement it in your app:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkcaGzhRjkc